# Does the device need to be rooted to read '/proc/cpuinfo' on an Android device?

Tags: android, cpu

I need to obtain CPU information on Android.  After some research, I found out that reading '/proc/cpuinfo' is one way to do it.  My question is - does the device need to be rooted to read '/proc/cpuinfo' on an Android device?

Is '/proc/cpuinfo' even guaranteed to exist on all Android devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need root privileges to read /proc/cpuinfo