# How to open and read "/proc/cpuinfo" on Android device in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, cpu, firemonkey

Could anyone advise me **how to open and read** "***/proc/cpuinfo***" on Android device in **Delphi**?

Original code:

```
var
  i: integer;
  FS: TFileStream;
  LBuffer: TBytes;
begin
  if FileExists('/proc/cpuinfo') then
    begin
      FS:= TFileStream.Create('/proc/cpuinfo', fmOpenRead);
      try
        SetLength(LBuffer, FS.Size);
        FS.ReadBuffer(Pointer(LBuffer)^, Length(LBuffer));
        for i:= 0 to Length(LBuffer) - 1 do
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LBuffer[i]);
      finally
        FS.Free;
      end;

    end;
end;
```

The problem is that the size of the FS is -1 and is therefore not as read ...

Comment: Naively one might expect a call to `TFile.ReadAllText` to do the job

Comment: It still displays an error "Cannot open file '/proc/cpuinfo' - permission denied ...

Comment: Well, I guess it's off limits

Comment: @David, [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8519867/33732) suggests that we should not *expect* it to be off-limits, so the problem might be deeper. J.P., please copy and paste the code you're using.

Comment: The original code was this: 

    var
      i: integer;
      FS: TFileStream;
      LBuffer: TBytes;
    begin
      if FileExists('/proc/cpuinfo') then
        begin
          FS:= TFileStream.Create('/proc/cpuinfo', fmOpenRead);
          try
            SetLength(LBuffer, FS.Size);
            FS.ReadBuffer(Pointer(LBuffer)^, Length(LBuffer));
            for i:= 0 to Length(LBuffer) - 1 do
              Memo1.Lines.Add(LBuffer[i]);
          finally
            FS.Free;
          end;
    
        end;
    end;

The problem is that the size of the FS is -1 and is therefore not as read ...

Comment: @J.P.jr. Just open the stream, and read bytes until no more are returned. Then you are done.

Comment: How when size of filestream is -1?

Comment: Call `Read` on the stream object and read chunks at a time. When `Read` returns a value less than the number of bytes you asked for, you are done.

Comment: Pls. show me some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple (tested):

```
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  ch: Char;
  RawLine: System.UnicodeString;
begin
  if FileExists('/proc/cpuinfo') then
    begin
      try
        RawLine:= '';
        ch := #0;
        FS:= TFileStream.Create('/proc/cpuinfo', fmOpenRead);
        while (FS.Read( ch, 1) = 1) and (ch <> #13) do
          begin
            RawLine := RawLine + ch
          end;
        Memo1.Lines.Append(RawLine);
      finally
        FS.Free;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Enjoy testing  ;)

Comment: Hmm. Char is 2 bytes wide. Better hope that your uninitialized high order byte happens to be zero. And you don't have non ASCII data.

Comment: Anyway, I hate it when this happens!!

Comment: You are right that Char is 2 bytes wide. For reading data is sufficient to use only one byte. The second byte Think of it as a reserve. Zero is monitored in "while". Non-ASCII data is not needed because in this case does not use Google.

Comment: You didn't understand my comment at all. Never mind. I can't force anyone to listen.

Comment: You do not have right to offend. I did not mean it maliciously.
What I did not understand you?

Comment: The high order byte of ch is undefined. You don't decode from UTF-8. Reading byte at a time is not efficient. I don't think the asker is interested in any of this though. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If the file stream reports a size of `-1` then you'll have to work a bit harder to read the contents. This is a virtual file, so it's not surprising that it doesn't behave exactly like a file and report its size. I expect it won't support seeking either.

Try this:

```
var
  Buffer: array [0..1023] of Byte;
  BytesStream: TBytesStream;
  BytesRead: Integer;
....
BytesStream := TBytesStream.Create;
repeat
  BytesRead := FS.Read(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
  BytesStream.Write(Buffer, BytesRead);
until BytesRead < SizeOf(Buffer);

// now the contents can be read from BytesStream.Bytes
// convert to a string using TEncoding
```

Simply put you read the file until there's nothing more to read.

Comment: I think it would be a real shame if you stopped providing answers just because the op ends up completely ignoring your (very sage) advice and accepts a poor solution. Your answers have been invaluable to me in the past, please keep posting them, regardless of who the op is.

Comment: @trooper Thanks. And of course I'll keep going. But perhaps not for this asker!